# AWS Cloudfront SetCookie in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to set a cookie to view private content from AWS Cloudfront

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html

They give an example cookie header:

```
Set-Cookie: Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=APKA9ONS7QCOWEXAMPLE
```

I created the following php code

```
setcookie (
  'CloudFront-Key-Pair Id',
  'MYID',
  0,
  '/',
  'mycloudfrontsub.cloudfront.net',
  true, 
  true
);
```

But the cookie is not set. The cookie is only set if I take out the domain name.

I think this is due to calling the setcookie in a script after session_start. I tried adding this, but it's required before session_start()

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'duvoxso6rm38g.cloudfront.net);
```

Do I need to do something like this?

```
//close local session, then open new one for aws
$id=SID;
session_write_close();
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'mysub.cloudfront.net');
session_start();
setcookie(...);
session_write_close();
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'originaldomain.com');    
session_start();
```

Comment: You are setting a custom cookie, so it has nothing to see with session cookies and your setcookie code seems right.

Comment: I never showed up in browser. I found another post saying PHP does not allow it due to security issues. I changed to signed urls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cookies do not show up in the browser because you send a cookie for a domain A from domain B. That is silently ignored by the browsers for security reasons. This is a browser feature not a PHP thing.

If you want to use signed cookies with CloudFront you need to use a CNAME for the CloudFront distribution that is a subdomain of you PHP server domain. A more detailed answer can be found under: https://mnm.at/markus/2015/04/05/serving-private-content-through-cloudfront-using-signed-cookies/

In short: assume you want to use the domain **example.com**. You serve the PHP files under **www.example.com**. Then you can use the CNAME **media.example.com** for the d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net. To send the cookies from the PHP side to the CloudFront Server you need to use the domain **example.com** in the Cookie.

The referenced site does also notice that you should use the PHP function **header()** to send the cookie, not **setcookie()**. This is because the setcookie function does some encoding that ruins the singing parameter created with the functions mentioned on the site.

Comment: Makes sense. I haven't tested it and went with signed urls instead. Thanks.