# cookies not working in php aws

Tags: php, cookies, amazon-ec2

I'm running into an issue where I can't set a cookie on an AWS EC2 instance running LAMP.

I have two simple pages, cookie.php and show_cookie.php:

**cookie.php**

```
<?php
setcookie('test', 'test', time()+36000, '/');
?>
<a href="show_cookie.php">show me the cookies!</a>
```

**show_cookie.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
<a href="cookie.php">go back</a>
```

When I navigate to cookie.php in Chrome and click on the link, the page echoes an empty array.  Also, if I inspect Cookies, there's nothing there.

I'm running PHP 7.0.16 with Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon).  This is such strange behavior.  Has anyone run into something similar to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Im not sure but maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564984

Comment: @Spingolini - Thank you for pointing it out, but I did see that question.  It seems like that person was having a slightly different problem where he was running into trouble using a cookie across different domains.

Answer (score 0):

In all my experience with cookies I've always included `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` as a fifth argument.  I don't believe you have to define $_Server. I believe it's defined during execution. If not you may have to define it as your domain or IP address.

```
setcookie("userid",$global['user-id'],time()+3600*2,'/',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

This is a link to the PHP guide for $_Cookies.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

This is a link to the PHP guide for $_Server. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> **Domain:**
>
> The (sub)domain that the cookie is available to. Setting this to a
> subdomain (such as 'www.example.com') will make the cookie available
> to that subdomain and all other sub-domains of it (i.e.
> w2.www.example.com). To make the cookie available to the whole domain
> (including all subdomains of it), simply set the value to the domain
> name ('example.com', in this case).